# Signification du verbe « instruire » dans « Le dossier sera instruit par nos services »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage

> Nous vous informons que votre candidature au poste suivant a bien été enregistrée  : Votre dossier sera instruit par nos services.

Quel est le sens du verbe instruire dans ce contexte ? Est-ce une tournure plus soutenue que, par exemple, sera traité ? Est-ce courante ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Instruire** fait partie du vocabulaire juridique. On dit qu'un juge d'**instruction** qu'il **instruit** un dossier.

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/instruire) :

> **B. − Instruire qqc.** DR.
>   **1.** *Instruire une cause, un procès, une affaire.* Rechercher et rassembler tous les éléments nécessaires (documents, témoignages, interrogatoires, pièces à conviction) afin qu'une affaire soit mise en état d'être jugée

Dans le cas de la réponse, instruire le dossier d'inscription signifie donc de manière soutenue qu'il sera soigneusement examiné, que les éléments éventuellement manquants seront collectés, que les informations seront vérifiées, etc. L'instruction est donc tout le travail préalable qui va conduire à la décision d'accepter ou non la candidature.

Answer (score 2):

Plus précisément appliqué au domaine de l'administration publique/du droit administratif, le verbe référant à « Préparer, mettre en état, étudier complètement » ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8996020)) et le nom (instruction) à la « Procédure d'examen d'un dossier par une autorité administrative » ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8355634)), pouvant s'étendre également à la prise de décision, quoiqu'on puisse y préférer *traitement* dans ce cas ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8355634)). Le terme est incontestablement bien connu pour toute personne familière avec la tradition civiliste (en France, par exemple), particulièrement en matière pénale (où le [juge d'instruction](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juge_d%27instruction_en_France) peut commander directement la police judiciaire), mais pas exclusivement.

Answer (score 1):

Dans un cadre juridique, l’instruction d’un dossier se passe à tous les niveaux, selon les compétences de chaque partie. Cela peut partir d’un conseiller juridique, vers ensuite un avocat, pour aboutir au juge, qui lui, instruit le dossier en son intégralité, afin de rendre son jugement en ayant pris en compte tous les éléments apportés au dossier, et entendu les arguments de toutes les parties.